# Spring AOP by annotation pointcut annotation not retrieve

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm using Spring AOP for intercept annoted  methods by @MyAnnotation. The intercepting is ok. but, unfortunately, i'm not arrive to have my annotation instance.

My Annotation :

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] description();
}
```

My Configuration Aspect

```java
@Aspect
public class OAuthAspect {

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(annotation)", argNames = "annotation")
    public void anyAnnotationMethod(MyAnnotation annotation) {
    }

    @Around(value = "anyPublicMethod() && anyAnnotationMethod(annotation)")
    public Object authorization(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MyAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {
        //annotation is null
    }
}
```

Example pointcut :

```java
@Service
public class ContextService {
    @MyAnnotation(description = {"de1", "des2"})
    public String getAll() {
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I can't retrieve the instance of the annotation.

if someone have an idea?

pc : edited

Answer (score 0):

For me the class `ContextService` does not even compile because of a typo in your annotation: `String[] descrition();` (note the missing "p") should really be `String[] description();`, then it compiles and I can also print the annotation instance.

Comment: for the "description" is juste an error to transcription. in my projet the 'p' is present and my projet compile, but the annotation instance is null :'(

Comment: Then you have a configuration problem. I tested the aspect on my machine in plain AspectJ and it works. If it does not in Spring AOP, it must be config problem. If you disagree, please provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) incl. Maven build via GitHub.

Comment: ok, it works, i had hard clean my projet and it's ok. i think that i had a problem in build projet. thank you for help :)

Comment: Would you mind accepting and upvoting my answer anyway? I pointed out your typo and confirmed that the aspect as such is okay and that the problem must be somewhere else in your project. As it seems, I was correct. Thank you.